Selenium error from unspecified arguments
I am trying to write a test for a HTML page. I am getting an error when my C# code attempts to click a button on the screen. The button works as intended when I click it manually, but my code produces this error:
Exception User-Unhandled:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverArgumentException:'invalid argument (Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.205)'

This appears to be an issue with versions (listed below), but I am up to date on everything relevant. I am able to use the same 'Click' command on other IWebElements, it only flounders on this one.
The C# code in question is simple:
using OpenQA.Selenium;

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(pathString));
element.Click();

I can see I am getting the correct IWebElement by looking at the element attributes, notably 'elementId' is "fileToUpload". The HTML is this:
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin:10px;">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
    <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" id="spanfile"></span>
</div>


.
The only thing remotely odd is that manually clicking on the text next to the button functions the same as clicking on the 'Choose File' button itself.
Versions:
Assembly WebDriver, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Selenium.WebDriver : 4.27.00
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver : 131.0.6778.20400
Chrome version 131.0.6778.205 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Selenium can't click on <input type="file"> elements. From W3C 12.5.1 Element Click


If the element is an input element in the file upload state return error with error code invalid argument.


You can try to click on the <span> or parent <div>, or use SendKeys() if you just want to upload a file
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(pathString));
element.SendKeys(pathToFile);

